# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector') when importing grapesjs in a nextjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, grapesjs

I am trying to import grapesjs in a nextjs project and I get the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

This seems to be that grapesjs wants to target the "#gjs" container referenced through it's id in order to load the editor inside, and it cannot find the corresponding element as the DOM is not rendered yet.

This is the code in my Editor.js component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import grapesjs from "grapesjs";

const Editor = () => {
  const [editor, setEditor] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const editor = grapesjs.init({
      container: "#gjs",
    });

    setEditor(editor);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="gjs"></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

This is how I try to render the Editor component in the corresponding page for "/editor" route

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import "../i18n/config/config";
import "grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import Editor from "../features/Editor/components/Editor";

// const EditorComponent = dynamic(
//   () => import("../features/Editor/components/Editor"),
//   {
//     ssr: false,
//   }
// );

export default function Home() {
  return <Editor />;
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

As you can see from the commented section, I have tried to dynamically import the editor component as I have seen this as a fix for alot of issues where an element could not be found because the DOM was not yet loaded, but it does not seem to work for me.

Edit: Adding `<script src="//unpkg.com/grapesjs"></script>` before the component to be rendered either in Editor.js component or in editor.js page while removing the grapejs import statement from Editor.js component `import grapesjs from "grapesjs"` allows the application to run but I still get the error in the console.

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import "../i18n/config/config";
import "grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import Editor from "../features/Editor/components/Editor";

// const EditorComponent = dynamic(
//   () => import("../features/Editor/components/Editor"),
//   {
//     ssr: false,
//   }
// );

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <script src="//unpkg.com/grapesjs"></script>

      <Editor />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

Edit: Screenshot of the produced error
[image]

Comment: Dynamically importing the `Editor` component should be the right approach to avoid SSR issues. Keep in mind that you'll need to `import "grapesjs/dist/css/grapes.min.css";` in the `_app` file as that's a global CSS stylesheet. What errors are you seeing when you dynamically import the component?

Comment: Yes I know about that, but same error persists when I use dynamic import nothing new. I will edit my question and provide screenshot of the produced error.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error, even without the dynamic import. See this working codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-morse-ymlqt0. Are you using the latest version of grapes.js?

Comment: I checked and it seems to work fine, but i have no clue why does this issue occur with me, one thing to note, when I make some changes in vscode and nextjs does fast refresh the error goes away, but when I refresh the webpage from the browser itself the error rises, making it more clear, this issue occurs only on the first render of the page.

Comment: Yes, that would be expected as the issue is caused by server-side rendering, which only happens when the page is first loaded. It's hard to debug the issue if we can't reproduce it, though. Would you be able to reproduce the error you have locally on a codesandbox project and share the link?

Comment: Well, I tried to reproduce the error in sandbox but I couldn't .. Meanwhile I created a new project in local environment and installed grapesjs package and I managed to reproduce the same issue, so if you managed to setup a local environment and figured out anything let me know.

Comment: @KarimHesham Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Luke Unfortunately, I had to switch to create-react-app in order to get going with my project. However, i can suggest you look into an approach to wait until the DOM element which will contain grapesjs like "#gjs" gets loaded into the DOM and then execute the code which initializes grapesjs "grapesjs.init()".
Let me know how it goes. I will be happy to figure out a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is wrong type in useState. U can try this.

```
const Editor = () => {
  const [editor, setEditor] = useState<Record<string, any> | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const editor = grapesjs.init({
      container: "#gjs",
    });

    setEditor(editor);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="gjs"></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

Search the library sources..
[image]

Comment: I think not, because using the same approach in a react.js app without nextjs does not produce this issue at all and works perfectly fine. So, I guess it is not a type issue rather than when the grapesjs.init method gets executed, it does not find a corresponding DOM element with id: #gjs because the DOM is not rendered yet .. that is what I think so far.